# SQL group by is bringing lots of duplicates

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I'm trying to group my data by OccDate, ParkingContextType, AuthorityId and of course, i would like to measure each sessions for each date/contexttype etc... However, I`m also trying to calculate the sum of sessions between a specific hour 8-18 for each date,ParkingContextType & AuthorityId.

The problem here is that 1 specific date is duplicated a lot and also the authority id etc... Something I'm doing wrong here and I cannot spot the problem,

Any one who can help me please?

Here is the SQL

```
WITH ParkeonCTE
AS
(
SELECT 
    OccDate = CONVERT(DATE, OC.LocalStartTime),
    TotalOccSessions = COUNT(OC.SessionId),
    AuthorityId,
    TotalOccDuration = ISNULL(SUM(OC.DurationMinutes),0),
    TotalNumberOfOverstay = SUM(CAST(OC.IsOverstay AS INT)),
    TotalMinOfOverstays = ISNULL(SUM(OC.OverStayDurationMinutes),0),
    (CASE
        WHEN OC.OspId IS NULL THEN 'OffStreet' ELSE 'OnStreet'
        END
    ) AS ParkingContextType,
    SUM(CASE
        WHEN CAST(OC.LocalStartTime AS TIME) >= '08:00:00' 
        AND CAST(OC.LocalStartTime AS TIME) <= '18:00:00'
            THEN 1
            ELSE 0
     END
    ) AS TotalRestrictedSessions
FROM Analytics.OccupancySessions AS OC
WHERE OC.AuthorityId IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY  CONVERT(DATE,OC.LocalStartTime), OC.AuthorityId,OC.OspId
 )
  SELECT OC.OccDate,
   OC.ParkingContextType,
   OC.AuthorityId,
   OC.TotalRestrictedSessions,
   SUM(OC.TotalOccSessions) AS TotalOccSessions,
   AVG(OC.TotalOccDuration) AS AvgOccMinutesDuration, -- wrong
   SUM(OC.TotalOccDuration) AS TotalOccDuration,
   SUM(OC.TotalNumberOfOverstay) AS TotalNumberOfOverstay,
   SUM(OC.TotalMinOfOverstays) AS TotalMinOfOverstays,
   CAST(AVG(OC.TotalMinOfOverstays) AS decimal(10,2)) AS AvgMinOfOverstays -- wrong
  FROM ParkeonCTE AS OC
  GROUP BY OC.OccDate, OC.AuthorityId, OC.ParkingContextType,OC.TotalRestrictedSessions
  ORDER BY OC.OccDate DESC
```

This is the end result, which is wrong...I should have less OccDate, with Two parkingcontexttype OnStreet/OffStreet for each authority id... But apparently I have loads of them.

[image]

And a minimal result it should be:

```
OccDate    ParkingContextType    AuthorityId .. (All of the calculated columns)
2019/11/18 OnStreet              32432-3424-32423
2019/11/18 OffStreet             32432-3424-32423
```

Comment: Simplify the problem. Show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text, no images. Take a look at [mcve].

Comment: `TotalRestrictedSessions` is different so `date,ParkingContextType & AuthorityId` is duplicating.

Comment: You're grouping by TotalRestrictedSesssions, which is different for each row returned.

Comment: The answer depends on what exactly would you like to group on. I see the reason behind duplicate rows is actually they are not duplicates (the calculated rows are different). So, if you would like to see them in a single row you have to put a rule on them such as getting sum, merging them into string etc.

Comment: @blackforest-tom Thanks - I understood now. However, if I will take out the TotalRestrictedSesssions from the Group By, it complains that it needs to be there, what I did is in the last SELECT I added a SUM(OC.TotalRestrictedSessions) in order to get rid of that problem. But I`m wondering if I have to SUM it here in the last select? Because I have already a SUM(CASE....)

Comment: @osumatu Thanks, makes sense... Please see my comment above, I`m in that doubt

Comment: @CsibiNorbert if it's not in the group-by clause, you have to put an aggregate function such as sum, max, min or whatever around it - otherwise there would be multiple values to deal with, which it can't, as it's grouped into one row. What exactly do you want to calculate? You're stating " However, I`m also trying to calculate the sum of sessions between a specific hour 8-18 for each date,ParkingContextType & AuthorityId." - You want the sum per group, right?

Comment: I want the SUM of TotalRestrictedSessions per group(date,parkingcontext and authorityid) - In this case the SUM(OC.TotalRestrictedSessions) AS TotalRestrictedSessions it`s enough, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `Aggregated function`

Change `SUM(OC.TotalRestrictedSessions)` in `Select` and Remove `TotalRestrictedSessions` From `Group By`

```
WITH ParkeonCTE
AS
(
 SELECT 
    OccDate = CONVERT(DATE, OC.LocalStartTime),
    TotalOccSessions = COUNT(OC.SessionId),
    AuthorityId,
    TotalOccDuration = ISNULL(SUM(OC.DurationMinutes),0),
    TotalNumberOfOverstay = SUM(CAST(OC.IsOverstay AS INT)),
    TotalMinOfOverstays = ISNULL(SUM(OC.OverStayDurationMinutes),0),
    (CASE
        WHEN OC.OspId IS NULL THEN 'OffStreet' ELSE 'OnStreet'
        END
    ) AS ParkingContextType,
    SUM(CASE
        WHEN CAST(OC.LocalStartTime AS TIME) >= '08:00:00' 
        AND CAST(OC.LocalStartTime AS TIME) <= '18:00:00'
            THEN 1
            ELSE 0
     END
    ) AS TotalRestrictedSessions
 FROM Analytics.OccupancySessions AS OC
 WHERE OC.AuthorityId IS NOT NULL
 GROUP BY  CONVERT(DATE,OC.LocalStartTime), OC.AuthorityId,OC.OspId
)
SELECT OC.OccDate,
   OC.ParkingContextType,
   OC.AuthorityId,
   SUM(OC.TotalRestrictedSessions),
   SUM(OC.TotalOccSessions) AS TotalOccSessions,
   AVG(OC.TotalOccDuration) AS AvgOccMinutesDuration, 
   SUM(OC.TotalOccDuration) AS TotalOccDuration,
   SUM(OC.TotalNumberOfOverstay) AS TotalNumberOfOverstay,
   SUM(OC.TotalMinOfOverstays) AS TotalMinOfOverstays,
   CAST(AVG(OC.TotalMinOfOverstays) AS decimal(10,2)) AS AvgMinOfOverstays
  FROM ParkeonCTE AS OC
  GROUP BY OC.OccDate, OC.AuthorityId, OC.ParkingContextType
  ORDER BY OC.OccDate DESC
```